# JA Slideshow Module's onclick not works in IE7

Tags: joomla, joomla1.6, joomla-template

I am using JA Slideshow in JA Community Plus. This works fine in all browsers except IE7. In IE7 onclick is not working. I am using transition-type = Animation. Animation, scroll direction vertical (scroll horizontal is working) Autoplay also works fine.

Comment: I have the same issue.